# Identify type of equality

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Please, help me to identify (how to name it) the type of the next equation.
We have $x_1,...x_n$ variables and trying to find $a_1,...,a_n$ and $b_1,...,b_n$ coefficients (all belong to $\mathbb{R}$ (or some field $\mathbb{K}$)), such that
the equation:
$$ a_1\cdot x_1 + a_2\cdot x_2 + ... + a_n\cdot x_n = b_1\cdot x_1 + b_2\cdot x_2 + ... + b_n\cdot x_n$$
is valid for any values of $x_1,...,x_n$ variables.

Of course, it's true only when $a_1 = b_1 ... a_n = b_n$. If we put $c_i = a_i-b_i$ we may reduce it to
$$ \forall x_1...x_n\in \mathbb{R} : c_1 x_1 + ... + c_n x_n = 0 $$
Then of course, $c_i=0$.

But how to name these equations? And sorry for this question - I feel like I'm not seeing something very simple.

Comment: Even if $a_k=b_k$ for each $k$ the equation need not hold since the set of values of the $x_j$ are unrelated to those of the $y_j.$ [On a second reading it seems you're viewing the $x_j,y_j$ as having some specified but fixed values, and after that looking for the $a_k,b_k.$ This seems more like the a's and b's are the unknowns.]

Comment: @coffeemath, sorry - fixed. we have only $x_1...x_n$ here.

Comment: One could call them "linear equations in $n$ variables" though I don't know if that name conveys much more than the equation itself, [Still seems odd to be looking for the $c_i$ (which one would think were the coefficients)]

Comment: I've found that "equations" that are valid for all variable values are called "identities" - i.e. linear equations that are true for any $x_1,...,x_n$

Still not sure if this is a final question, because this just "identities" comes from elementary mathematics, where they capture some fixed correspondences between algebraical terms. Probably such "linear identities" have another names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the riddle of the year is solved : )
I've found the answer in the Charles Proteus Steinmetz book "Engineering Mathematics". The equation that is valid for every x is called ... drum-roll ... identity.
Shame on me :/